# Function template parameter pack followed by template parameter and specialisation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Can a template parameter pack used in the definition of a function template, be followed by another template parameter, when that parameter is only given its required default value, in the definition; and not the declaration? Consider the following example:

```
template <typename ...Ts, typename T>
auto sz(Ts...);

template <typename ...Ts, typename T = int>
auto sz(Ts...) { return sizeof...(Ts); }
```

I find that GCC and Clang disagree on this (GCC gives a compilation error).

Comment: I've tested three other cases similar to yours according to [this code](https://gist.github.com/sfranzen/5137b63ffdec5036593aa58bc5039219), and your example is the only case where current Clang and GCC versions differ. As discussed below the answer, I think Clang is wrong to allow this. However, I'm also curious to know: why would you want this specific, exotic arrangement?

Comment: Hi @sigma. This was part of a SFINAE selection system within someone else's sketchy code. I removed the SFINAE to make the MWE you see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**-- EDIT --** corrected after an initial misundertanding.

I suppose g++ is right and clang++ is wrong.

According the C++17 standard, 17.1.11,

> template parameter
>   pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template
>   parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list (11.3.5) of the function template or has a default
>   argument (17.8.2).

So a template parameter, with a default value, should be accepted after a variadic pack.

The problem is: we can set the the template default values only in function declarations or also in function definitions (when distinct from function declarations)?

In fact, you can simplify your problem simply with

```
template <typename>
void foo ();

template <typename = int>
void foo ()
 { }

int main ()
 {
   foo();
 }
```

accepted by clang++ and rejected by g++.

This isn't completely clear to me but, in 17.1.9 I read

> A default
>   template-argument
>   may be specified in a template declaration.
>   A default
>   template-argument
>   shall not be specified in the
>   template-parameter-list
>   s of the definition of a
>   member of a class template that appears outside of the member’s class. A default
>   template-argument
>   shall
>   not be specified in a friend class template declaration. If a friend function template declaration specifies a
>   default
>   template-argument
>   , that declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of the
>   function template in the translation unit

This fragment explicit that "A default template-argument may be specified in a template declaration". Non in "definition".

Exclude that "A default template-argument shall not be specified in the template-parameter-list s of the definition of a member of a class template that appears outside of the member’s class", so I initially concluded that a template generic function can specifies default template-argument in "definition" but this part is about a "class template", so the template-argument are about the class, not about the member.

As pointed by sigma (thanks!) in 17.1.10 we can read

> The set of default
>   template-argument
>   s available for use is obtained by merging the default arguments from
>   all prior declarations of the template in the same way default function arguments are

Again: "declarations" and no "definition".

So I suppose clang++ is wrong and g++ is right.

Comment: Interesting. I reckon the code ought to compile *only if* the default for `T` is specified in the initial declaration, because of 17.1.11 and additionally 17.1.14: "The set of default template-arguments available for use is obtained by merging the default arguments from all *prior* declarations of the template in the same way default function arguments are" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @sigma - Looking back for a moment... maybe you're right. I suppose I've misunderstood the part regarding the "the definition of a member of a class template": it's a class template, not a member template of a class. Answer corrected (I hope). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @sigma and @max66. Plenty to think about there. It is looking like GCC is correct..one question I still have is whether the 17.1.14 quote would imply that adding a second declaration of `sz`, where `T` is given a default value, and removing `T`'s default value from the definition, should lead to valid code? (Again here Clang is happy, but GCC unhappy.)

Comment: @user2023370 - sorry but I cannot reproduce: given `template <typename = int>
void foo ();

template <typename>
void foo ();

template <typename>
void foo ()
 { }` and the call `foo();`, both g++ and clang++ compile in my Linux platform.

Comment: @user2023370 - sorry, I've misunderstood: given `template <typename>
void foo ();

template <typename = int>
void foo ();

template <typename>
void foo ()
 { }` and the call `foo();`, my clang++ compile and g++ gives an error... uhmmm... it seems to me that, in this case is right clang++ but I'm not sure: the examples for 17.1.14 are about multiple class declarations, non function class declarations.

Comment: Yes, I wonder if the author of the 17.1.14 quote was thinking of class templates at the time? Still not sure what the conclusion should be.

Comment: @user2023370: The section is not specific about the kind of template, so I think it applies equally to function templates. I did some re-reading and of further relevance are section 15, saying that parameters can only follow a parameter pack if they either have a default or can be deduced from arguments, as well as 16, "A template-parameter shall not be given default arguments by two different declarations in the same scope." I read this as completing the answer: no, in your example, only the first declaration can (and must) give a default for `T`.